# How Disable Automatic Attachment when sending a mail in Stored Process

Tags: email, stored-procedures, sas

I create a web application in Chaining SAS stored process. In this application, in the last screen, a mail is sending automatically with a report in the body of it with no attachment.

but when i checked the mail, there are two attachments: a text file and a htm file. These two attachments contains the same message on it:

```
<WARNING> this message is sent automatically and the identity of the sender can not be technically verified </WARNING>
```

I would like disable this two attachment and i don't know how do it.
Code that I use is like this:

```
FILENAME outmail EMAIL
  SUBJECT= "subject"
  FROM= "&mail_report_to."
  TO="&list_receiver_to."
  CC="&list_receiver_cc."
  CT="text/html lrecl=32000";

ods msoffice2k file=outmail style=HTMLBlue metatext='name="viewport"
               content="width="device-width"' options(pagebreak="no");

   --- Code to generate Report ---

ods msoffice2k close;
```

I searched about msoffice2k tagset and filename in sas documentation but nothing about this problem.

If someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `FROM= "&mail_report_to."`

It's 'spoofing' the "from" address so that may remove the warning you are seeing.

Comment: I remove the From instruction, but there are always the attachments